# Python Library for Comparing Fingerprints

Tags: python, django, reactjs

Is there any library in python that can I easily compare fingerprints? 
I want to build a student attendance system using fingerprint, my frontend will be ReactJS and Django as backend. Like, you need to save the fingerprints of every student in the database and you will retrieve it for comparing.

I already google but there are no specific result for my question.

Comment: what kind of fingerprint scanner do you have? there will be something like that for your model https://github.com/bastianraschke/pyfingerprint

Comment: I will still consider that? I thought it will just compare the img of finger print?

Comment: Your question in the comment is more a statment, I dont know if you will consider it.You have an actual fingerprint scanner right? You probably make a modelfield for your user and then compare the saved value in the db with the value you got over your front-end to authenticate a user.

Comment: Did you find any solution?  I have the same request, having the image of the fingerprint in PNG and a database of images in PNG to compare, need the Python library to make the comparison and identify the user.

Answer (score 0):

Got it guys, the scanner will just give me output to save in db. I thought I will save figerprint as image in db, and  retrieve the image to compare.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still tryna implement it but check out [libfprint](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libfprint/libfprint), it's a C library but can be interfaced with python. Takes care of all problems from enrolling (device drivers) to verification and identification.